# Spot light not working in render or the game engine

Tags: rendering, game-engine, light

When I render it the light doesn't appear.
In more detail, the Spot kind light does not appear in rendered or in the game-engine. I do have GLSL shading activated.
By the way this worked perfectly in 2.65 but it won't work now even if I re-download 2.65.

[image: buggy]

Comment: Could you add more details to your question? (e.g. A screenshot or a .blend)

Comment: FYI, P is the game engine mode, not sure if 'test mode' is the best description for it.

Answer (score 2):

Spotlight only works well in the game engine when the draw mode is set to 'GLSL'. You can change that setting in the attribute editor.

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot the OP is using material shading, which uses GLSL regardless of the setting in the properties region (or attribute editor, whatever..)

Comment: exactly how do I get where you are Mike Pan?

Comment: @mrcw Press `N` in the 3D view, then scroll down to *shading*.